# Hadoop: How to write to HDFS using a Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop and trying to learn. I am trying to run the below Hadoop sample code in Eclipse on Ubuntu Linux. I have  Hadoop v 2.7.0 and I have the required jars.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml")); 
    Path pt=new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/myhome/a.txt");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

When I run the application in Eclipse I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/PlatformName`. The `hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar` file I am referencing does not contain the class application is looking for. I am referencing that jar file Hadoop/common folder.

Any help is resolving this issue will be much appreciated.

If I create a jar file of the class for above above code and run it using `hadoop -jar <jar file> <class name>`, it works. So I am wondering whether it's possible at all to run a Hadoop Java application from Eclipse or command line without using hadoop command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the JVM doesn't load all required Hadoop artifacts.

If you are a maven user, please ensure that you have these dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>${hadoop.client.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using Maven. What Jars I am missing?

Comment: The best manner to handle all dependencies through eclipse is Maven. Otherwise there is a lot of required Jars to import manually. When you execute the "hadoop -jar <jar file> <class name>" command it works, it is normal, because the "hadoop" executable file load all needed Jars on the classLoader.

Comment: OK. I think I got the answer I was looking for. It's not mandatory to run Hadoop client applications using the hadoop jar <> <> command. They can be run from Eclipse also.